# How do I string format variables that require additional formatting

Tags: python, formatting, rounding, string-formatting

I am doing a project where I have to print a pay summary for someone based off of information like their hours worked and their pay rate, etc. In the print summary, the spacing is very specific to keep the calculations right-aligned under their specified title (except Premium is centered) so I have been using string formatting to input the variables to keep the formatting consistent between test cases. However, there are some variables that require additional formatting, and I was told that I can not have nested braces.

Here is how I coded the formatting:

```
print(formatted_work_date + '{:>15}'.format(float(hours_worked)) + '       ' + '{:^7}'.format(user_input_line_2_list[1]) + '{:>11}'.format(str(empl_hourly_payrate)) + '{:>16}'.format(str(round(gross_pay, 2))))
```

And this is the output:

```
Workdate            Hours       Premium       Rate       Gross Pay       
12/23/2020           13.3         0%         71.45          950.29
```

SO the spacing is correct however, the variable hours_worked is supposed to be a float with 2 digits after the decimal(13.30 not just 13.3), so to get the additional zero I had written '{:.2f}'.format(float(hours_worked)), and I don't know how to place those braces into the braces to format it. Hopefully this question makes sense!

Comment: If you are using python version 3, then it would be better to use f strings, which provide much easier formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Use the format `'{:>15.2f}'` to specify that the field width is right-aligned ('>'), 15 characters ('15'), and it's formatted as a float with 2 decimal places (`.2f`).